# Magento - show all review of a single product on the same page

Tags: php, magento

This code helps me show the data stored in the reviews array but whenever i try calling the variables individually i get  an error. So how can i display the variables indiviually.

```
 <?php $reviews = Mage::getModel('review/review')->getResourceCollection();
      $reviews->addStoreFilter( Mage::app()->getStore()->getId() )
  ->addStatusFilter( Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED )
  ->setDateOrder()
  ->addRateVotes()
  ->load(); 
  print_r($reviews->getData());
```

This is line where i get the error:

```
   echo $reviews->getTitle();
  ?>
```

the error is  Fatal error:  Call to undefined function. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used Magento, but I think you have to iterate through reviews. Try this.

```
<?php 
$reviews = Mage::getModel('review/review')->getResourceCollection()
  ->addStoreFilter( Mage::app()->getStore()->getId() )
  ->addStatusFilter( Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED )
  ->setDateOrder()
  ->addRateVotes();

if (count($reviews) > 0) {
  foreach ($reviews->getItems() as $review) {
    // Individual review
    echo $review->getTitle();
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $ReviewsCollection = $this->getReviewsCollection()->getItems();

if( count( $ReviewsCollection ) ) {
    $x = 1;

    foreach( $ReviewsCollection as $_review ){

        // get review title
        echo $_review->getTitle();

        $_votes = $_review->getRatingVotes();
        if (count($_votes)){
            foreach ($_votes as $_vote){
                echo $_vote->getRatingCode().' - '.$_vote->getPercent().'%<br />';
            }
        }

        // get review date
        echo $this->formatDate($_review->getCreatedAt()).'<br />';

        // get review detail
        echo $_review->getDetail().'<br />';

        // get how wrote the review
        echo $_review->getNickname().'<br />';

        // because you cant setPageSize with this collection it's best to break the loop.
        if($x == 4){ break; }

        $x++;
    }
}
```